# Emacs: using emacsclient

Tags: emacs

I always set up emacs running in server mode, and every time I update Ubuntu, the procedure to do this changes.

Even though I have all the same setting in my `/.bash_aliases` and `/.emacs`, it will not work.

I have emacs 24.3.x (whatever the most recent version is), I have AUCTeX cvs, and TeX Live 2013 installed.

In my `./bash_aliases`, I have

```
emacs = 'emacsclient -t --alternate-editor='
```

The relevant information in my `/.emacs` is

```
;; Start server and set directory                                               
(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs%d" (user-uid)))
(server-start)

(custom-set-variables
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-show-compilation t)
 '(TeX-newline-function (quote newline-and-indent))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t))
```

Problems only occur opening LaTeX files. Sometimes it says another server is running and other times it says:

```
dustin@dustin:~/Documents/NUPOC/NUPOCSoln$ emacs SolnNUPOC.tex 
emacsclient.emacs24: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
("emacs")
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Error while loading 50dictionaries-common: Symbol's value as variable is void: debian-aspell-only-dictionary-alist
Loading paren...
Loading paren...done
Warning: no abbrev-file found, customize `abbrev-file-name' in order to make mode-specific abbrevs work. 
Starting Emacs daemon.
Restarting server
```

I read in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html#Emacs-Server) a footnote that:

---

Some programs use a different environment variable; for example, to make TeX use ‘emacsclient’, set the TEXEDIT environment variable to ‘emacsclient +%d %s’.

---

There is no mention (that I can find) on where and how to set the TEXEDIT environment.

1. How do I set the TEXEDIT environment?
   or
2. How can I set up emacsclient to work?

**This set up worked prior to having to re-install everything.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the server to start and work for `synctex`.  It will still issue this message:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Loading paren...
Loading paren...done
Loading server...
Loading server...done
Warning: no abbrev-file found, customize `abbrev-file-name' in order to make mode-specific abbrevs work. 
Starting Emacs daemon.
Restarting server
Emacs daemon should have started, trying to connect again
```

What I changed was my `/.bash_aliases` and `/.emacs`.

If you open emacs first without specifying a file and then open a file, you will not receive the the warning above.  I have no idea why it works flawlessly in that order opposed to going directly to a file.

For my aliases, I now have:

```
# emacs aliases for server mode
alias emacs='emacsclient -t -s server --alternate-editor='
```

The `-s` is short for `--socket-name=`; therefore, `-s server` is `--socket-name=server`.

I found this by `M-x describe-variable` then `server-socket-name` and the name should output for you.
Also, we can locate the directory with the same `M-x` and then `server-socket-dir`

In my `~/.emacs`, I changed:

```
;; Start server and set directory                
(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000" (user-uid)))
;(server-start)  has been commented out
```

In the custom set variables, I added: `'(server-mode t)`.

I don't know if there is a difference between `(server-start)` and the custom variables `'(server-mode t)`.  I will test out using one or the other and both to see what happens later.