# emacsclient issue when using pdfsync on Mac OS X

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

I'm trying to sync between emacs and skim, and this is the site that I reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899845/emacs-synctex-skim-how-to-correctly-set-up-syncronization-none-of-the-exi

Following the guide, I could make the setup that I could Shift-Cmd-Click on emacs/AUCTeX to launch skim.app, however, I could not make the backward-sync. When I click Shift-Cmd-Click on Skim.app, nothing happens. This is the configuration from skim.app.

[image: enter code here]

I checked that reverse sync is working with other editors such as `TextMate`, so the issue seems to be with `emacsclient`. I have `(server-start)` in init.el.

I double-checked to launch server with `M-x server-start` command from emacs, 
This is what I got from `emacsclient` command:

```
a> emacsclient -s server a.tex 
emacsclient: connect: Connection refused
emacsclient: error accessing socket "/tmp/emacs501/server
```

Using the hints in [Emacs: using emacsclient](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176190/emacs-using-emacsclient) doesn't help, as I find no `server-socket-name` variable assigned.

What seems wrong is that `emacsclient -s server a.tex` tries to use `/tmp/emacs501/server` while `server-socket-dir` points to `"/var/folders/sj/6xmft7c105ngpzh4dv9kc2dc0000gn/T//emacs501"`. I copied the server file into `\tmp/emacs501` to relaunch to get this error:

```
a> emacsclient -s server a.tex 
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: error accessing socket "/tmp/emacs501/server"smcho@smcho mass2015> emacsclient -s server mass2015.tex 
Waiting for Emacs...
-emacs-pid 19104
-error Unknown&_command:&_/Users/me/Desktop/a/a.tex
```

What might be wrong? How to make `emacsclient` working and how to check if it works right?

Comment: Here is a related thread, perhaps it may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26471957/2112489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Command line, the location of emacsclient should be specified.

[image]

### Other setups

#### latexmkrc

If you want to use latexmk, these configuration setup should be added in `~/.latexmkrc`.

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
$pdf_previewer = 'open -a skim';
$clean_ext = 'bbl rel %R-blx.bib %R.synctex.gz';
```

#### emacs setup for AucTeX

```
;; AucTeX
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "<S-s-mouse-1>") #'TeX-view))
          )
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

;; Use Skim as viewer, enable source <-> PDF sync
;; make latexmk available via C-c C-c
;; Note: SyncTeX is setup via ~/.latexmkrc (see below)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push
    '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))

;; use Skim as default pdf viewer
;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
;; option -b highlights the current line; option -g opens Skim in the background  
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
     '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))
(server-start)
```

#### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899845/emacs-synctex-skim-how-to-correctly-set-up-syncronization-none-of-the-exi
- http://www.stefanom.org/setting-up-a-nice-auctex-environment-on-mac-os-x/